# Text field blank when adding a newline character JavaScript pdf form

Tags: javascript, pdf, textbox, newline

I am creating a custom pdf form using JavaScript custom calculations and I want to add a text field with two lines separated by a newline character.  I use this.getField() to get values from multiple text boxes.  Then I want to join two of them into one text field separated by a new line.  I can join the two strings and pass it into the text field but as soon as I add '\t' or '\n' to the string it won't show up in the text field.  If I use the JavaScript console to call the value of the string it shows up correctly but I can't figure out why it the text filed shows up blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the ASCII representation of carriage returns, `String.fromCharCode(13)`:

```
string += "Carriage return comes after this " + String.fromCharCode(13);
```

This is discussed in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980416/how-can-i-insert-new-line-carriage-returns-into-an-element-textcontent). I found that answer by googling ["insert newline into text field javascript string"](https://www.google.com/search?q=insert+newline+into+text+field+javascript&oq=insert+newline+into+text+field+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5897j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=insert+newline+into+text+field+javascript+string)

Comment: I tried this and I can't seem to get it to work.  It shows up in the JavaScript console formatted correctly but still doesn't show up in my text field.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  I had the properties set in the text field menu set to multiline but I had to set the field to multiline with Javascript. 
    field.multiline= true;

Comment: Maybe you should post that as the answer?