# Unable to retain line breaks when writing text file as blob

Tags: javascript, html, web, blob

I have a text area that contains text that I want to output to a text file for users to download.

I'm using this function to grab it when users click the save button

```
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    alert(textFileAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}
```

But the line breaks aren't retained. They exist in document.getElementById("inputText").value; but not in the text file created from the blob.

Comment: You can find the answer to this from one of the answers to the following post (check out the answer about CODE 13):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980416/how-can-i-insert-new-line-carriage-returns-into-an-element-textcontent

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.  This seems to be working for me:

```
textToWrite = textToWrite.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
```

Comment: Actually, you should do like this: `.replace(/([^\r])\n/g, "$1\r\n");`. This way, it avoids matching `\r\n`, which would end up as `\r\r\n`.

Comment: unless your text has multiple newlines in a row, then you want this to happen

Comment: @quemeful - you want what to happen? The original answer code? Or Ismael's suggested change? Put another way - what if my text has single newlines in some places, and multiple newlines in others - what is the correct code for this? The answer supplied seems to work for this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

change

```
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
```

to

```
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain',endings:'native'});
```

May not work in IE and I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Worked in IE too. Both `new Blob([content], { type: "octet/stream", endings: "native"  })` and `new Blob([content], { type: "text/plain", endings: "native" })` worked in IE11.

Comment: @SNag What is `octet/stream`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when the text arrived from JSON. the solution was:

```
 textToWrite.replaceAll('\\r\\n',"\r\n")
```

Answer (score -5):

You should put something like that into your code.

```
textToWrite.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: Also I don't know if <br /> would work for me since the end goal is to have a plain text file with line breaks in it. Not an html file.

Comment: The blob is expected to be `text/plain`, not html.