# How to pass row-by-row in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the code

```js
$('.Text').each(function() {
            var data = $(this);
            temp = data.text();
            
            fs.appendFile('output.csv',  temp , function(err) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
            });
});
```

In first three iterations temp is

> "I am komal"
>   "Nice to meet u"
>   "ok?"

But it comes as a single line

> "I am komal""Nice to meet u""ok?"

I want each of them to be a row in a single column

Comment: Where are you running this code? Server or Browser? Please give some more context. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a carriage return should add move you to next line.

```
$('.Text').each(function() {
            var data = $(this);
            temp = data.text() + String.fromCharCode(13);

            fs.appendFile('output.csv',  temp , function(err) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
            });
});
```

Link to [similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980416/how-can-i-insert-new-line-carriage-returns-into-an-element-textcontent).

Answer (score 0):

`fs.appendFile` doesn't automatically add newline characters to the content you pass it - you need to do that yourself:

```
        fs.appendFile('output.csv',  temp +"\n", function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
        });
```