# Why does getting value from data-attribute affect the text

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with some syntax, mostly why the `data-attribute`(HTML5) is affecting the text in the way it is.

Please consider this example which does what is expected

```
<div id="s"></div>    

<script>

var ele = document.getElementById("s");
var txt = "this is it \n and done";
ele.innerText = txt;

</script>
```

The result is I see 2 lines in HTML due to the `\n`. This is expected

The task means I need to change the way we work into

```
<div id="s" data-txt="this is it\nand done"></div>

<script>

var ele = document.getElementById("s");
var txt = ele.getAttribute("data-txt"); 
ele.innerText = txt;

</script>
```

Note we're now using the data attribute of `data-txt`. The issue is this renders the text verbatim, meaning I see 1 line: `this is it\nand done`

https://jsfiddle.net/he4ydvva/

The fact I can't even use replace (`ele.getAttribute("data-txt").replace('\n','blah');`) suggests that although I see \n, the computer is reading something different (maybe the charcode value or similar)

Why does this happen and how do I prevent it?

**Edit**

I have seen [How can I insert new line/carriage returns into an element.textContent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980416/how-can-i-insert-new-line-carriage-returns-into-an-element-textcontent) but this won't suffice as I need the string to exist within the data-txt and concatenating as `"this is " + String.fromCharCode(13) + "` is not valid for HTML5

Comment: It would appear that the rendering engine takes the `\n` and converts it into a `<br>` in the first case, however since the page has already been drawn in the second example the literal text is used.

Comment: `\n` is second case is literal slash and n not a new line. https://jsfiddle.net/he4ydvva/1/

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: So what is it that you're actually trying to achieve? Do you want to set the inner text of a tag using javascript that includes a newline? If `innerText` (non standard anyway) doesn't work, use `innerHTML`, `textContent` or `document.createTextNode`. Do you want to read text from a data-attribute which includes a newline? Then actually *include* a newline character in that data-attribute. `\n` in html is not the same as in javascript (see jcubics comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing HTML with JavaScript.

`\n` is a JavaScript character. `data-*` attributes are HTML. For inserting newline **in HTML**, you should use the HTML entity `&#10;` (Newline) or `&#13;` (carriage return) or their combination.

HTML doesn't understand `\n`, `\r` and so on.

Also note,

```
<div>This is a line \n Another one</div>
```

This won't insert newline but the code below will:

```
<div>This is a line &#10; Another one</div>
```

Check out the full list of [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Comment: `You are confusing HTML with JavaScript.` - That was the type of answer I was looking for. Very clear, thanks

Comment: My general opinion is to use `<br>` and not the CRLF chars because it allows for predictable behavior with the css `white-space` attribute. If you are using this method, do take a look at this as well http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp. eg: the code above will be disrupted by the style `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you should use:

```
ele = document.getElementById("t");
txt = ele.getAttribute("data-txt").replace(/\\n/g,'<br>'); 
ele.innerHTML = txt;
```

Explanation:
The `\` char is an escape character and so to specify a new line, you need to use two `\\` so that the 1st one escapes the meaning of the second. The second one is then treated as a normal char and is read together with the n as `\n`.
Further, you must replace that with a `<br>` because a browser will not respect CRLF chars.

Here is your example on jsfiddle fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/4eurrzgx/

```js
    
    var ele = document.getElementById("s");
    var txt = "this is it \n and done";
    ele.innerText = txt;
    
    
    ele = document.getElementById("t");
    txt = ele.getAttribute("data-txt").replace(/\\n/,'<br>'); 
    ele.innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
 <div id="s"></div>
 <p>
 ***
 </p>
 <div id="t" data-txt="this is it\nand done"></div>
```

Comment: `/\\n/g` if you want to replace all new-line chars.