# Insert "\n" in ractive-tooltip

Tags: ractivejs

I would like to add a "\n" in a [ractive-tooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ractive-tooltip)

I tried differente possibilities like "\n", "& nbsp;", "< br/>".... but nothing works for me...

I want something like this:

"Line 1: text1,

Line 2: text2,

Line 3: text3"

and i get this:

"Line 1: text1, Line 2: text2, Line 3: text3"

Can someone help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`ractive-tooltip` uses [`element.textContent` to add the text](https://github.com/JonDum/ractive-tooltip/blob/master/src/tooltip.js#L50). It doesn't look like it was designed to do newlines. However, there are [ways to force newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9980416/575527) on content added via `element.textContent`.