# How do I get a CR/LF when setting textContent?

Tags: javascript

How do I get a CR/LF when setting textContent?
I've tried a couple things (below) but these do not work. The `\r\n` has no effect, the `<br />` is displayed literally.

```
document.getElementById("lbResult").textContent = "\r\nmyID"
document.getElementById("lbResult").textContent = "<br />myID"
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330671/add-linebreak-to-textcontent-or-innertext-only-in-chrome)

Comment: @JamesG. `innerText` is not a standard property, it's one of Microsoft's own making which most other browsers recognise even though it's not part of the spec. The problem is that Firefox doesn't recognise it

Comment: @Joe Yeah, I was just linking a similar question that explored the problem.

Comment: If `lbResult` is a `<pre>`, then "\n" will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, as far as I know. You **can** do it with `innerHTML` though:

```
document.getElementById("lbResult").innerHTML = "<br />myID";
```